# [VB.NET]Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to add value of column from selected row on my datagridview to Collection(but I get same error if I do it with List or Array)

**CODE:**

```
Dim zdgv = MyDataGridView

    For a = 0 To zdgv.SelectedRows.Count - 1

        MsgBox(zdgv.Rows(zdgv.SelectedRows(a).Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Try
            MyCollection.Add(zdgv.Rows(zdgv.SelectedRows(a).Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
        End Try

    Next
```

> ex.Message = *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*
>
> ex.InnerException = *empty*
>
> ex.InnerException.Message = Makes program crash, goes to code screen,
>   highlights *MsgBox(ex.InnerException)* line, and gives error: *Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object*

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
Using QuickWatch on zdgv gives me all info. Using it on Rows after it(zdgv) says: *'Rows' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

P.S. Yes I've googled, but none problem was similar. Yes I've searched here but no info. I've tryed r/visualbasic too - nothing...
I've even tryed search for c# related stuff with this error - nothing. :/

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT1:** I've tryed make non-databound datagridview in new project, and add one value from it to collection - same error. I guess I should go google about "Setting Reference of Object to an Instance of an Object".

**EDIT2:** This one was fail - newbie mistake.

**EDIT3:** using quickwatch on

```
zdgv.Rows(zdgv.SelectedRows(a).Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

it shows right value(correct one, without throwing errors) = "1".

Comment: One of the objects or properties you are referencing is `null`. Do you know on which line the error occurs?

Comment: @valverij *Do you know on which line the error occurs?* Probably the single line between `Try` and `Catch` ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is MyCollection? - did you forget to make a New on it?

Comment: At top of code - just below `public class classname` and above first sub I've this: `Public eilutesnumeriukas As Collection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works like a charm on my side.

Did you forget a New on your MyCollection?

```
Dim zdgv = MyDataGridView
Dim MyCollection As New Collection
For a = 0 To zdgv.SelectedRows.Count - 1

    MsgBox(zdgv.Rows(zdgv.SelectedRows(a).Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
    Try
        MyCollection.Add(zdgv.Rows(zdgv.SelectedRows(a).Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
            MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
        End If
    End Try
Next
```

Comment: THANKS. It worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH. 

My city is atm one of most popular among tourists in Lithuania - it's Telsiai. If you ever come here - I get you a beer. Like seriously.

Comment: @ZebriukasDryžiukas I shall remember that :)

Comment: Are you inviting only Matt?

Comment: FREE BEER FOR EVERYONE!
And as we know Russians are superior hackers, and we also know they love vodka. So I can assume Beer could improve programming skills, right?

Answer (score 1):

ex.InnerException is null, and you try to access is Message attribute. It's a normal behavior.
You should try something like

```
        Try
            MyCollection.Add(zdgv.Rows(zdgv.SelectedRows(a).Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                 MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
            End if
        End Try
```

InnerException is not null only if a sub method threw an exception under it.

Comment: CSharp Basic .NET? :D `null` in VB.NET is `Nothing` and `!=` is `<>`

Comment: By the way, maybe I'm wrong, but it'd be `If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then`...

Comment: I was using that to try find error, but still thanks to both. At the moment trying to do this on new project with simple datagridview. Gonna see if error repeats.

Comment: @ZebriukasDryžiukas if your initial problem is not about ex.InnerException, please tell debug and give us more informations about the breaking part

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer `If Not (...) Is Nothing` Or `If (...) IsNot Nothing` is excatly the same in `VB.Net `

Comment: @Matt - I just want to insert value of cell from datagridview to Collection. Using code I've shown in posts gives _Object reference not set to an instance of an object_ error. I've used `Try Catch` just to make it easier debugging.

Answer (score 1):

> At top of code - just below public class classname and above first sub
>   I've this: Public XXXXX As Collection

You don't' create an instance of `collection` and then you try add some items to it.

It should be:

`Public XXXXX As New Collection`

Or you need to create a new instance somewhere else before access it

`XXXXX = New Collection`

Comment: Yes @Matt Already answered it - still thanks.

P.S. I was using MyCollection name in this thread to cause less confusion with unknown words.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Solution I found**
Basically, the error is that your code is making use of a non-existing row.

You will merely need to turn to false the datagridview `AllowUserToAddRows` property. Then all your normal loops will work properly.

```
Dim zdgv = DataGridView1
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In zdgv.Rows
    ListBox2.Items.Add(row.Cells(1).Value.ToString) 
Next
```

or

```
For i as integer = 0 to datagridView1.rows.count - 2
    'enter code here

Next
```

MK :)